# Finding an unbiased estimator for the variance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

While doing some statistics exercises I found a question that I don't know how to solve. The question is as follows:

Let $X_{1},...X_{n} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2$ $\in R^{+}$ is unknown and density function:

$f_{X_{i}} (x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}$, $x \in R$

a) find an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ based only on the first observation $X_{1}$ and determine its variance.

My thoughts: I know that the first observation (i.e. the smallest) is computed as $X_{1} = n (1-F(x))^{n-1} f(x)$, but I need to compute the integral of the above density function, but is there an easier way? Can you give me some hints?

Comment: Are you sure that $X_1$ refers to the smallest observation? If you say $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are iid, that implies that $X_1$ is not always the smallest. The notation for the smallest observation is something like $X_{(1)}$.

Comment: E(X1^2) = sigma^2 +  mu^2 ,here mean = 0 , hence E(X1^2)  = sigma^2 , hence X1^2 is unbiased estimator for population variance. you can find variance of X1^2 easily

Comment: You're right, the notation is different. But then what's the point of the exercise? What is the difference between considering the first observation and any other one?

Comment: Perhaps the point of the exercise is to show there is more than one unbiased estimator.  Later you can show the different estimators can have different variances

Comment: The point is that you can use _only one_ observation, it does not matter that it is the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the estimator $X_1^2$. 
It is unbiased since $$\mathsf{E}X_1^2=\sigma^2$$ Its variance is also $$\mathsf{Var}(X_1^2)=\mathsf{E}X_1^4-\mathsf{E}^2X_1^2=3\sigma^4-\sigma^4=2\sigma^4$$

Comment: $X_1$ notation doesn't mean the smallest. It implies only one (i.e. the first) observation.